# Pintos test cases : Why are some written in c and some in ck file extension?

Tags: perl, pintos

In `pintos/src/tests/threads`, some of the tests are written in c, while some written in perl (ck file), and the other tests have both c and ck files.

two questions :

1. Is .ck extension used for perl scripts? For some reason, I am not getting satisfiable explanation about the .ck extension.
2. Why is some written in c and others written in ck?

Answer (score 2):

In Pintos projects, .ck files show you the desired sequence of print outputs.
.c files contain the test cases themselves